# Embedding liquibase inside JBoss EJB JPA JTA environment

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, liquibase, jta

I'm embbeding liquibase inside our server so we can warn the user about the syncrhonization problems in the database before it even starts.

What we did is to get the connection from entityManager.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
DataSource currentDatasource = (DataSource) emf.getProperties().get("hibernate.connection.datasource");
try {
   connection = currentDatasource.getConnection();
 } catch (SQLException e) {
    ....
 }
```

And then feed Liquibase with it. (We get database object first)

```
 Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("postgresql-master-changelog.xml", new CompositeResourceAccessor(clFO, fsFO, threadClFO), database);
 liquibase.reportStatus(true, "",  new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))));
```

The problem now is that it seems to start working but we get

```
You cannot rollback during a managed transaction!
```

So we don't know how to do all with this. Only alternative is to create a new fresh connection without the JTA management. But how can we do this?

Is there any other alternative?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: which version of JEE / jboss are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a "necroquestion" due to its publication date but I faced this issue just a couple of minutes ago trying to deal with Liquibase from singleton session bean in WildFly 10.

So, the problem can be solved on configuration level. Since transactions are content managed by default this behaviour should be changed for the bean, that deals with Liquibase. Bean managed transactions can be switched on using EJB deployment descriptor - `META-INF/ejb-jar.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_2.xsd"
    version="3.2">
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>MyLiquibaseRunnerBean</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.example.MyLiquibaseRunnerBean</ejb-class>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: Yes in fact we switched to Spring a while after the question and everything is setup and worked.